# How do I put an onclick and a return false statement in the same submit button?

Tags: javascript, html

From what I understand, the default treatment for return false is:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return false" />
```

However in my code I would like to have a submit button run a separate js function `onclick` which will give ajax output based on which radio button the user selected.

But since I'm using ajax and my js function to take care of the output, I want the submit button to return false.

But if I am already using `onclick` to point to the function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="jsfunction()" />
```

where do I put return false?

Can I have 2 `onclick` statements?

The other option I would imagine is that if I know I am not going to be submitting the form regardless of which value the function returns, that it shouldn't be a submit button at all?

But if that's the case, is there a button I can code in html that looks the same as submit but doesn't have the submit property?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try to add your method (jsmethod) to your form onsubmit handler like this

```
<form onsubmit="jsfunction(); return false;">
```

and remove the input onclick handler.

Answer (score 14):

just do like this

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return jsfunction()" />
```

change in function

```
function jsfunction()
{
  //you code 
  return false;
}
```

or just try if you dont want to change function

```
<input type="submit" onclick="jsfunction();return false;" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="jsfunction();return false;" />
```

or just use a button intead of a submit button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="jsfunction();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot have 2 `onclick` declarations but you can call multiple functions in the same `onclick` like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="jsfunction();anotherFunction();" />
```

And in the other function you can have:

```
function anotherFunction(){
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You would need to return the value from anotherFunction.