# Posting data to sql database without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery

the problem is that i am unable to insert data in my database without reloading 
i have tested it without the `note_sql.js` and my `note_sql.php` works fine but there seems to be a problem in my `js` file if some body could point me in the right direction it would be wonderful

**Index.php**

```
    <form id="noteform" action="note_sql.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="note"></input>
    <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Save Note" />
    </form>
    <span id="result_note"><span>
   <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery/note_sql.js"></script>
```

**note_sql.js**

```
$("#sub").click(function(){

var data = $("#noteform: input").serializeArray();
$.post($("#noteform").attr("action"),data,function(info){$("result_note").html(info); });
    clearInput();
}); 

$("#noteform").submit(function(){
    return false;
});

function clearInput(){
    $("#noteform :input").each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `$("#noteform" ).submit(function( event ) {` instead of `$("#sub").click(function(){`

Comment: Maybe this is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064179/how-do-i-put-an-onclick-and-a-return-false-statement-in-the-same-submit-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Jquery Ajax the working code is given below :
please add ID to Note Form Element :

```
<pre>
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#sub").click(function () {

                    var name = $("#note").val();
                    var message = $("#message").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "note_sql.php",
                        data: "name=" + name,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }

                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
</pre>
```

Comment: i did try the above code but i get redirected to note_sql.php

Comment: SO remove note_sql.php from form action

Comment: okay it works now but i do not need it in a alert box it needs to come in a span area `<span id="result_note"><span>`
how would i dothis

Comment: use $('span#result_note').html(data); in place of alert(data);

Comment: Thanks for your hel @rajveer u have been great

Comment: Thank you dear  @jake123