# How to stop next page to be loading

Tags: javascript, html

In my project, while a particular button is clicked I want to stop the next page appearing. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function checkcond() {
    check_value=document.getElementById("chkvalue");
    if(check_value==null){
        alert(check_value);
        document.firstform.textview.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and button code is:

```
<form id="payment_form" name="payment_form" action="<?php echo site_url("cont/accept");?>" method="post">
    <input id="chkvalue" name="chkvalue" type="hidden">
    <button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="checkcond()">
      <b>Make a Payment</b>
      <span class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
```

Here after checking the check_value I want to keep my current page while it is null. How should it be done? Is there any function for that?

Comment: In checkcond() I dont see any reload or next page code..  Is your button type submit..  Can you add button code and also how you are calling checkcond()

Comment: i have added the button code.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13064245/8492116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to remove inline javascript

and use like this

```
document.getElementById('payment_form').onsubmit = function() {
    return checkcond();
};
```

or if you want to use inline method, change onclick method like this

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return checkcond()"><b>Make a Payment</b>
```